# Django Queryset: group by two field values

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset, django-annotate, django-postgresql

I have a model like this

```
Class ExchangeMarket(models.Model):
base_currency = models.ForeignKey(Currency)
quote_currency = models.ForeignKey(Currency)
... various other fields
```

And some entries like

```
base: EUR, quote: USD ...
base: EUR, quote: USD ...
base: USD, quote: EUR ...
base: BTC, quote: USD ...
...
```

I need to find entries sharing the base/quote combination, i.e. in my example that's the first **three**

How to create such a queryset? If I do something like

```
ExchangeMarket.objects.all().values('base_currency', 'quote_currency').annotate(pks=ArrayAgg('pk'))
```

I will only find exact matches with same bases and quotes (like EUR/USD, first **two** of my entries) while I need to find both EUR/USD and USD/EUR. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can work with [**`Least`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/database-functions/#least) and [**`Greatest`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/database-functions/#greatest) here:

```
from django.db.models.functions import Greatest, Least

ExchangeMarket.objects.values(
    cur1=Least('base_currency', 'quote_currency'),
    cur2=Greatest('base_currency', 'quote_currency'),
).annotate(pks=ArrayAgg('pk'))
```

This will then add the primary key to the two same items.

That being said, I would advise to do some post-processing in Python, and work with [**`.groupby(…)`** <sup>[Python-doc]</sup>](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import attrgetter

from django.db.models.functions import Greatest, Least

items = {
    k: list(vs)
    for k, vs in groupby(
        ExchangeMarket.objects.annotate(
            cur1=Least('base_currency', 'quote_currency'),
            cur2=Greatest('base_currency', 'quote_currency'),
        ).order_by('cur1', 'cur2'),
        attrgetter('cur1', cur2),
    )
}
```

We even can do additional processing where we also add the `(k2, k1)` entry to the dictionary, if the `(k1, k2)` entry is already passed:

```
for k1, k2 in list(items):
    items[k2, k1] = items[k1, k2]
```

This means we can obtain the `ExchangeMarket` objects for `items['EUR', 'USD']` and `items['USD', 'EUR']`.

Comment: WOW! Thanks, that's an amazing solution and great additional info 